# The following code "à = &agrave; = ", eval("&"+a+"grave"+";") ] does not yield à = &agrave; = à

Tags: concatenation, eval, yield

See the compile version below, it seems to work more or less fine, but I would like to obtain the same translated results (apart from the line breaks) output to the console.

```
<div id="did"></div>
    let tmp="",
    ast = `${"*".repeat(5)}`,
    chr = new Array( "","a","c","e","ae","æ","oe","œ","i","o","u","y","A","C","E","AE","Æ","OE","Œ","I","O","U","Y","Ð")
    let len=chr.length,
    sp= new Array( "acute","grave","cedil","circ",
    "lig","rdm","slash","tilde","uml"
    for(let m=0, spl=sp.length ; m<spl ; m++) {
        tmp += `${ast}
        ${sp[m].toUpperCase()} ${ast}
        <br><br>`;
        for(let k=0;k<len;k++) {
            let s = `&amp;${chr[k]}${sp[m]};` ;
            let t= `&${chr[k]}${sp[m]};`;
            tmp+=`[ ${chr[k]} ] => ${s} ${ast}
            « &${chr[k]}${sp[m]}; »`;
            //if(t.slice(1)===s.slice(5)) tmp+=` ${".".repeat(3)}`;
            tmp+=`<br>`;
        }
        tmp=`${tmp}<br><br>`;
    }
    document.getElementById(`did`).innerHTML=tmp;
    console.log(tmp);
```

It yields this at the body element :

```
[ ] => &acute; ***** « ´ »
[ a ] => &aacute; ***** « á »
[ c ] => &cacute; ***** « c »
[ e ] => &eacute; ***** « é »
[ ae ] => &aeacute; ***** « &aeacute; »
```

...

And this at the console :

```
[  ] => &amp;acute; ***** « &acute; »
[ a ] => &amp;aacute; ***** « &aacute; »
[ c ] => &amp;cacute; ***** « &cacute; »
[ e ] => &amp;eacute; ***** « &eacute; »
```

Many thanks.